# jQuery plugin undefined options

Tags: jquery

I've got a really simply jquery plugin that I'm just trying to read
the options from but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. When
I try to run this I get an **"options is undefined js error."**

Here is my code:

```
(function($) { 

$.fn.extend({
headerSlideshow: function(){

    var defaults = {
            padding: 20,
            mouseOverColor : '#000000',
            mouseOutColor : '#ffffff'
        }

    var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

},
header: function() {
    this.headerSlideshow(options);
    setInterval( "this.headerSlideshow(options)", 1000 );
}
});

}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: have you passed any options in calling script ? and you need to provide options parameter in `headSlideshow` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have to accept an `options` parameter in your `headerSlideshow` and `header` functions:

`function(options)`

Also, don't pass a string to `setInterval`. This will use `eval`. Better pass a function:

```
header: function(options) {
    var element = this;
    this.headerSlideshow(options);
    setInterval(function() { element.headerSlideshow(options); }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `this` inside the `setInterval` is *not* what you think it is.  You need to cache `this`.

Comment: this works perfect thanks @Chips_100 but why would I pass a function?  couldn't i run this: element.headerSlideshow(options);

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly. In your question, your first parameter to `setInterval` is a string, containing code. This should be avoided, as that calls `eval` under the hood, to evaluate that code expression.
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

instead, it is better to pass an anonymous function to `setInterval`  which contains the code to run.